# Apple Appstoreconnect shows different icon than app

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, app-store-connect, apple-developer

My IOS app has all the app icon files properly set in `Assets.xcassets` in Xcode. The icon is also displayed correctly in the device during test.
I see a different icon (Ionic icon) in the Appstoreconnect beside the app name. I am not sure if that is ok or I am missing some steps to change this.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to upload Icon manually with Xcode V 9 and above. If you have changed icon with new build. New version icon will be updated once app is made live.

Comment: Look for app icon with size 1024 within your assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

@tapas-mukherjee You don't need to do anything. once you will select the build to review then it will automatically pick the same icon and start showing there. I faced the same issue but found this when was submitting the app.